# How to stop the package when Error by vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I'm creating script component at SSIS by vb.net

I'd like to show message "ERROR" and the running package stops.

I tried it by using ConponentMetaData.FireError(0, me.String, "ERROR", String.Empty, 0, False)

When I run the package, the message showed, the script component become green, but the package still runs.

I thought ConponentMetaData doesn't have the function to stop the package.
I need to find out the way how to stop the package and show the message.

I want to know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just set the script task status to failure and let it stop on it's own?

```
ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, me.String, "ERROR", String.Empty, 0, False)
Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
Exit Sub
```

That will fail the script task and the package should stop.

If for some reason you still want the script task to succeed and stop the package running after that, you could define a variable in your package, something like `ScriptFailure` with data type Int32. Add it to your script task as a ReadWriteVariable and then set it to some value, 1 for instance, in your script task when you raise an error

```
Dts.Variables("User::ScriptFailure").Value = 1
```

Then add a precedence constraint to the connection to the next task. Select expression and put `@[User::ScriptFailure] != 1` as the expression. The package will then only proceed to the next task if the `ScriptFailure` parameter is not equal to 1.

A third option would be to call [RunningPackage.Stop()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.runningpackage.stop.aspx). I've never had reason to use this myself, but something like this should work.

```
        Dim app As Application =  New Application() 
        Dim pkgs As RunningPackages =  app.GetRunningPackages("yourserver") 

        Dim p As RunningPackage
        For Each p In pkgs
            If p.PackageName = "MyPackageName"
                p.Stop
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
```

It's worth noting that the package doesn't stop straight away when Stop is called according to the documentation in the link above

> There may be a delay between the time a stop request is issued and the
>   time that packages actually stop.

Comment: my boss give me detail today.

Comment: Thank you to answer my question.I will ask different question after day.